# C++ container for compound index that allows ignoring sub-index at look-up

Tags: c++, stl, indexing, set

What is an appropriate container for compound index that allows ignoring the sub-index at lookup? It should not use more resources than a container without this feature.

F.e. given the index

```
struct index_t
{
    index_t(unsigned key_, unsigned subkey_)
        :   key(key_)
        ,   subkey(subkey_)
    {}
    unsigned key;
    unsigned subkey;
};
```

and inserting

```
index_t(1,11)
index_t(2,21)
index_t(2,22)
index_t(2,23)
index_t(3,31)
```

all the elements with f.e. `key == 2` and ignoring the `subkey` have to be looked up.

Also lookups with given `key` **and** `subkey` must be possible. So using a multiset/map with `key` as the only container's key is not a solution.

Comment: I found a solution and will post it after the 8 hours timeout.

Comment: `multimap<key_t, multimap<subkey_t, data_t> >` would be a solution but introduces some overhead in storage and progamming.

Comment: @hpc: Thankyou for doing Stack Overflow properly. Incredibly rare in a 1rep user.

Comment: Won't post my solution because @StilesCrisis solution is just perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
std::set<index_t>  mySet;
```

And for searching for all items with a given key and any subkey, do

```
std::pair<std::set<index_t>::iterator, std::set<index_t>::iterator> range;
range.first = mySet.lower_bound(index_t(key, 0));
range.second = mySet.upper_bound(index_t(key, UINT_MAX));
```

That'll preserve 2*log n performance.

Comment: Of course, thanks! If iterating from the lower_bound the call of `upper_bound()` is not necessary.

Comment: Ah, and it should be `range.second = mySet.upper_bound(index_t(key+1, 0));` because `upper_bound()` (unlike `lower_bound()`) returns an iterator to an element that is strictly greater.

Comment: Glad to help! Not quite sure what you mean about `upper_bound` not working, though.

Comment: I don't mean `upper_bound()` is not working. In the first comment I meant that `upper_bound()` is not needed if the iteration starts at the lower bound goes until `key` changes. In the second comment I noted that for the upper bound `index_t` must be set to the next greater index because the iteration would normally break at `it == range.second`.

Comment: I think either `lower_bound(index_t(key+1, 0))` or `upper_bound(index_t(key, UINT_MAX))` would do the right thing. But I think `upper_bound(index_t(key+1, 0))` would include entries with the value `key+1, 0`. Try it and see if you disagree.

Also, were you still going to post your solution? Or was it more complicated than this?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I won't post my solution because it is rather a hack. It used `find()` and a special comparator  that does not compare the subkeys if one of the subkeys is 0.

Comment: OK, well if this is the approach you intend to use, please confirm it as an answer by clicking the checkmark. Thanks :)